# Laravel 5.0 ORM Relations

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to select a 'Site' from a Users 'Organisation'.
I can successfuly retrieve a User's Organisation (as an Organisation object) by using

```
$user->organisation
```

but when I try to retrieve the sites belonging to the organisation using:

```
$user->organisation->sites
```

I get every site in my DB returned (as a collection).

My User Model's organisation relationship:

```
public function organisation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organisation', 'organisation_id');
}
```

My Organisation Model's User and Site relationships:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
}

public function sites()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Site');
}
```

My Site Model's Organisation relationship:

```
public function organisation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organisation');
}
```

**User Table**

- id
- organisation_id
- name
- email
- password
- last_login
- persist_code
- reset_password_code
- remember_token
- created_at
- updated_at
- deleted_at
- responsible_to

**Organisations**

- id
- name
- created_at
- updated_at
- deleted_at

**Sites**

- id
- organisation_id
- name
- address
- account_code
- created_at
- updated_at
- deleted_at

I've included everything I think will be useful here but I've missed anything I will add it as requested.

I have the following workaround in place but I am still unhappy with why the above is not working as expected.

```
$organisation = Organisation::where('id', $user->organisation->id)->first();
$site = Site::where('organisation_id', $organisation->id)->first();
```

The above workaround returns the first site from my table that does genuinely have a relationship with my user model.

If I remove `->first()` I get a collection of sites that are associated with my user through the organisation rather than all from the table.

Thanks

Comment: you defined that organisatio can have more sites "public function sites()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Site');
}" this is why you get collection.

Comment: Sorry, I do actually  expect a collection but only those sites that have their organisation_id that matched the organisation in question not every site from the table.

Comment: Try `$user->organisation->sites()->get()`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get every site from my table.

Comment: try to post your db's tables structure

Comment: @Moppo Apologies I've added the table layouts now.

Comment: Does `Organisation::first()->sites` return correct collection or it's still all the sites from the db?

Comment: @AndrewMalinnkov This returns all sites also. I guess the problem lies somewhere between the Organisation and Site model then!

Comment: @Joe1992 definitely. I don't know, try to remove second argument from `User`'s model `organisation` method. The `organisation_id` argument - try to remove it.

Comment: @AndrewMalinnkov Thanks, but sadly I've already tried this, I made no difference as far as returning every site (no perceivable difference to the application either)

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but please take a look in your database: are the values of `organisation_id` definitely different?

Comment: @Tim I have checked the table and there are definitely different organisation Ids in the table. I'll update my answer with a work around that I have working that demonstrates this.

Comment: What do you get when you `dd` this? `Organisation::first()->sites()->toSql()`. It should be something along the lines of this: ``"select * from `sites` where `sites`.`organisation_id` = ? and `sites`.`organisation_id` is not null"``

Comment: @ThomasKim When I use 'dd(Organisation::first()->Sites()->toSql());' I get the string "from [sites]".